# Is it possible to post pictures in comments?

Tags: feature-request

I was wondering if it is possible to post pictures in comments? It might be useful for clarification of difficult questions. If not then could it be a feature?

Comment: Why the down votes? It's a meta question!

Answer (score 3):

I'd argue a picture, posted in a comment, should really be made as a clarifying edit to the answer or to the question -- wherever the comment was going to be made.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible currently, but we can leave it here tagged as feature request. The site developers monitor questions tagged as [feature-request](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) so they will see both this and the votes that people have left for the feature to be implemented.

(Don't be alarmed if people down vote it - votes here work differently than on the main sites)

Answer (score 0):

If there really is a need for adding a picture to a comment (which I doubt due to the nature of comments here), there is always the possibility to add a link to the picture uploaded somewhere.